# Delete table rows in non-spatial database using arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, sql-server, database

Working on a python script that does a bit of spatial analysis on a few layers, a spatial join of those layers, and then pulls data from a couple of other tables and holds them all in an `in_memory` table to be written out at the end. The idea is that this script would be run on a schedule every morning.

After all the processing is done, the in_memory table needs to be written to an existing table in a non-spatial database to be consumed by a third-party application.  I also need to be able to clear out that table before the new data is written.

I have found that `UpdateCursor`, `Truncate`, `DeleteRows` etc. don't work for me in this other database as the table is not registered with Geodatabase.  I am unable to do this as it's not stored in a geodatabase and I can't turn it into one.

How can I delete rows in this table in the non-spatial third-party database using arcpy?  Once the table is empty I can use `arcpy.da.InsertCursor` to insert new rows without any issue.

ArcGIS Desktop 10.3
Both the non-spatial and spatial database servers are running SQL Server 2012

```
# Delete/Truncate/Delete Rows of third-party DB table
nonGeoDB = "Database Connections/NonGeoDB.sde/NonGeoDB.dbo.ALoad"

# Delete Rows doesn't work
arcpy.DeleteRows_management(nonGeoDB)

# Update Cursor with deleteRows doesn't work
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(nonGeoDB, 'SEQ') as delcursor:
    for row in delcursor:
        delcursor.deleteRow()
```

> 001323 : Input rows must be stored as a registered object in a geodatabase.

---

**EDIT** The main reason I'm trying to use arcpy over pyodbc is that I can then just use read-made database connection files that are stored securely on the server so that updates can be made to those connection files without having to modify connection settings within the `.py` directly.  If pyodbc can read the connection settings from one of those files, then that possibly would be the best option.

Comment: Are you unable to connect to this database using ArcCatalog? If you can, you should be able to register as versioned there.

Comment: @MaryBeth I can connect using ArcCatalog, but this is **not** a geodatabase, so I cannot register this table with the geodatabase.  Also I don't want to register as versioned.

Comment: Ugh. Sorry. I swear I read that there was an error with versioning. It didn't make sense to me that you couldn't just turn it on with Catalog...hence my comment. Sorry for the misread on my end.  :/

Comment: This appears to be more of a pure Python issue.  Have you tried using ODBC (pyodbc) to this external database?  I've used [ArcSDESQLExecute](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/arcsdesqlexecute.htm) to issue arbitrary SQL to a database, but only to *geodatabase-enabled* databases.

Comment: @Vince it just seems so odd that SearchCursor works, InsertCursor works, but DeleteRow doesn't.  I'm really hoping to stay away from pyodbc - trying to keep it all as much within arcpy as possible.

Comment: DeleteRows uses the registered rowid from the selection set.  No rowid, no selection set, no delete.  Nothing odd about that.

Comment: I have to agree with @Vince that for a non-ArcGIS table it doesn't really make sense to use arcpy. Instead use the tools specifically written for this purpose, eg pyodbc

Comment: @Vince OK yes that does make sense.  I guess my question now is whether it is possible to tell arcpy what my rowid column is, as the table has one, it just isn't an Esri defined ObjectID.

Comment: You don't need to specify a rowid column.  As mentioned by both @Vince and @Stephen Lead, you should connect to the database table via [pyodbc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyodbc) and execute this statement `DELETE * FROM table_name;` to delete all rows.

Comment: You can't have a *registered* rowid column without an `sde.sde_table_registry` table to register it in.  No geodatabase, no registration

Comment: If you want to delete all rows, you should issue `TRUNCATE TABLE tablename` -- way faster

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't pound this octagonal peg in that round hole. The Connection object can return all but the password.

Comment: @Vince `ArcSDEAQLExecute` did the trick - I had missed your mention of that tool until just now, but it works the same way as pyodbc except that it will also read the .sde connection file (which I confirm can be to a gdb-enabled or non-enabled database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured this one out.  And apologies to @Vince - I see you mentioned this in a comment but I completely missed it until right now when I came to post this answer.

The tool `arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute()` is the arcpy equivalent of `pyodbc`, but unlike pyodbc, ArcSDESQLExecute will in fact read a `.sde` connection file (so I don't need to pass login details through to the script).

```
# Delete/Truncate/Delete Rows of third-party DB table
nonGeoDB = "Database Connections/NonGeoDB.sde"

sqlConn = arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute(nonGeoDB)

sqlQuery = """DELETE FROM [NonGeoDB].[dbo].[ALoad]"""

sqlConn.execute(sqlQuery)
```

I can then follow this up with the `arcpy.da.InsertCursor()` to insert the new records into that same table, as the Insert Cursor works to non GDB tables, it's just the Update Cursor that doesn't work.

Comment: I'd still recommend `TRUNCATE TABLE tablename` as the SQL to delete all rows.

Comment: @Vince unfortunately you need `ALTER` permissions to perform a `TRUNCATE TABLE`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the old copy of the table anymore you could use:

```
if arcpy.Exists(table): arcpy.Delete_management(table)
```

to get rid of the old table, then use `arcpy.TableToTable_conversion()` (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/table-to-table.htm) to convert your attributes to a dbase table in your SDE.

Alternatively you'd have to register/version your table and set permissions that allow you to make edits on that table. When making edits on a versioned table in an SDE you have to start an editing session as well (I've had to do this for update/insert cursors) (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/editor.htm)

Also, if you can create a database connection in python, you can use the same info to set up your pyodbc connection.

```
server_name = "YOUR.SERVER.NAME"
database = "YOUR_DATABASE"
connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER={};DATABASE={};TRUSTED_CONNECTION=yes'.format(server_name, database))
```

The `server_name` and `database` correspond to the "Instance" and "Database" in the "Add Database Connection" window through ArcCatalog. You may have to change the "Driver" string for the pyodbc connection, but that will correspond to the "Database Platform" in the add database connection window.

[image]

PYODBC: https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyodbc/wikis/GettingStarted.wiki